# node_modules/express-openid-connect/index.d.ts:7:8 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'openid-client'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, npm, express-openid-connect

I am encountering an error while attempting to install `npm install express-openid-connect`. The library seems to be unable to find `openid-client`. I have attempted to resolve the issue by installing the types, creating a separate `d.ts` file with `declare module 'openid-client';`, downgrading `express-openid-connect` and `openid-client` libraries, but have been unsuccessful. Each time I receive a different error. Can someone assist in resolving this issue?

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
> npm run build

node_modules/express-openid-connect/index.d.ts:9:8 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'openid-client'. '/myproject/functions/node_modules/openid-client/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/openid-client` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'openid-client';`

9 } from 'openid-client';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/express-openid-connect/index.d.ts:11:15 - error TS2724: '"jose"' has no exported member named 'JSONWebKey'. Did you mean 'JSONWebKeySet'?

11 import type { JSONWebKey, KeyInput } from 'jose';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/express-openid-connect/index.d.ts:11:27 - error TS2305: Module '"jose"' has no exported member 'KeyInput'.

11 import type { JSONWebKey, KeyInput } from 'jose';
                             ~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/express-openid-connect/index.d.ts:9
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot different things. I ended up just trying to play with versions and for some reason, at some point I decided to add more specifically `openid-client` version and it worked! The following configuration made it happen:

```
"express-openid-connect": "^2.7.3",
"openid-client": "^5.1.6",
```

I hope this helps someone else because it was extremely annoying